# "Unknown function 'Workday2' in validation expression"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a VBA module named 'Module1' under "Database (New Microsoft Access Database).

Here is the code (credit goes to another Stackoverflow user):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function Workday2(start_date, days, Optional Holiday As Variant) As Date
    Static xlApp As Object
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Workday2 = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.workday(start_date, days, Holiday)
End Function
```

I am using this function in my table design view under a field for "Default value." My intent is to set the default value 5 business days from the current date.

I would like to use it as

Default value: Workday2(Date(),5)

But I get an error that the function is unknown despite using a public function in a module.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c6c9ada2-c3f4-4c6b-a2cf-710121281e7c/default-value-in-table-not-recognizing-custom-function?forum=accessdev

Comment: Code works for me in textbox properties, not table design.

Comment: You cannot use UDF (user defined function) for DefaultValue in Table Design.  Instead you'll need to call this function in a form or control event before allowing new records to be saved.